# Display image in right hand corner of dynamic element

Tags: css, positioning, image

I have an "article-box" that is used for a few different pages with 2 different widths. I have an image that i would like to display in the top right hand corner of each of these boxes. how could i use css to display the image correctly in the top right hand corner for each box?

i have the following css code which doesn't quite work, thanks in advance.

```
.wide-article-box {
    @extend .article-box;
        padding: 20px;
        max-width: 900px;

    #badge {
        position: relative;
        max-width:260px;    
    }

    #badge img {
            position: absolute;
        border-width: 0px;  
    }       
}
```

and in the view

```
    <div class="wide-article-box">
     <!--text etc -->
      <div id="badge">  
        <%= image_tag "BLH_BADGE.png" %>            
      </div>
       </div
```

Comment: What does the `@` have to do with CSS?

Comment: @DavidThomas that's probably a SASS mixin

Comment: i have a css style called article-box and as i want to inherit most of the styles from that without having to write it again, I use extend to inherit the properties then overide as need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wide-article-box {
    @extend .article-box;
        padding: 20px;
        max-width: 900px;
        position: relative;

    #badge {
        position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        max-width:260px;    
    }

    #badge img {
        border-width: 0px;  
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the `float` property of CSS. It will also automatically wrap text around the image (or any block element).

```
#badge {
    float: right;
    max-width: 260px;    
}
```

P.S. you might also have to use `clear` css property but that will depend on the nature of the DOM. just read up on on `float` and `clear` properties